# OpenWRT Barrier Breaker - Router does not route

Tags: nat, openwrt

I've upgraded my TP-Link 1043 router to OpenWrt 14.07. Everything is perfect, Wifi and LAN are bridged, LAN machines can access each other by name, I can SSH into the router, and the router can access the internet on the `pppoe-wan` interface.

The is one small problem though. The router does not route. The internet is not accessible from the LAN. With one funny exception: DNS lookups do work.

The `/etc/config/firewall` file contains the following section:

```
config forwarding
    option src 'lan'
    option dest 'wan'
    option mtu_fix '0'
```

But when I list the POSTROUTING chain of `iptables`, there is nothing

```
# iptables -L POSTROUTING
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

# iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source        destination
```

### UPDATE

So I tried adding the masquerading manually, and that seems to work:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o pppoe-wan -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source        destination
MASQUERADE all  --  anywhere      anywhere
```

And voilá, suddenly the internet works from the LAN.
But why is the iptables rule not added based on the UCI config in `/et/config/firewall`?

### UPDATE 2

I added the fixing iptables rule to the custom rules on the web interface. Then I checked, it was indeed inserted into `/etc/firewall.user` which is included into `/etc/config/firewall`. But after a reboot, the rule is not listed by iptables. And no internet in the LAN. Seems like a UCI config parsing issue...

### UPDATE 3

It turns out I had no firewall at all. My `/etc/config/firewall` is completely ignored. It's just that the lack of filter rules is difficult to notice.

Comment: There's no `POSTROUTING` chain in the filter table, it's in the nat table. So you would have to do: `iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING`

Answer (score 2):

Masquerading is only set up by OpenWrt if the output `zone` is configured for it.

For instance:

```
config zone
        option name 'wan'
        option masq '1'
        #...everything else
```

Or in the web interface:

[image: WAN masquerading in OpenWRT GUI]

Comment: I've just checked, the option you mentioned is set.

Comment: @SzG I'd guess you have something else going on. Better look at the _entire_ firewall config. I also suggest you set `mtu_fix '1'` or you will have trouble passing packets out to the Internet due to path MTU issues.

Comment: According to Barrier Breaker docs, mtu_fix is deprecated.

Comment: @SzG Deprecated maybe, but that's not the same thing as nonfunctional. It's your router, you can ignore me if you want. :)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'll try, but my UPDATE 2 points to a different direction.

Comment: @SzG Hm. Well yes, UCI can be really touchy. I don't think they've worked all the bugs out of it yet. Worst case you could just reset the config and try again.

Comment: Funny thing is, this is the factory firewall config. Not only Barriers are Broken, it seems. :-)

Answer (score 0):

UCI config parsing seems to be broken. Issue temporarily fixed by adding a line to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o pppoe-wan -j MASQUERADE
```